# File Search With Multiple Directories To Search

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am using this syntax to Recursively scan 1 directory for all `*.mdb | *.accdb` file types.  My issue is that I need to scan more than 1 directory.  I need to scan

> C:\Test\
>   
> R:\
>   
> T:\

How can this be modified in order to scan multiple directories?

**Note**
I commented out the line of codes below as I no longer need it to be a recursive search, but did not want to have to re-write an entire procedure.

```
'Set objSubFolders = objFolder.Subfolders
'For Each objSubfolder In objSubFolders
'    RecursiveFileSearch objSubfolder, objRegExp, matchedFiles, objFSO
'Next
```

Code ->

```
Option Compare Database
Sub RefreshLinkedTables()
'Dim Fileout As Object
'Dim fso As Object
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim colFiles As Collection
'Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = ".mdb$|.accdb$"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

Set colFiles = New Collection

RecursiveFileSearch "C:\Test\", objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO

For Each f In colFiles
    Set accapp = New Access.Application
    accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase (f)
    On Error Resume Next
    accapp.Visible = False
    Set db = accapp.CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
      If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*") Then
        'Relink here
        tdf.RefreshLink
      End If
    Next
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
Next
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objRegExp = Nothing

End Sub
Sub RecursiveFileSearch(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByRef objRegExp As Object, _
                ByRef matchedFiles As Collection, ByRef objFSO As Object)

Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objSubFolders As Object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)
For Each objFile In objFolder.files
    If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then
        matchedFiles.Add (objFile)
    End If
Next
'Set objSubFolders = objFolder.Subfolders
'For Each objSubfolder In objSubFolders
'    RecursiveFileSearch objSubfolder, objRegExp, matchedFiles, objFSO
'Next
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing
'Set objSubFolders = Nothing

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
As per the comment by @Tim Williams - I edited my code to read like below, but on the line that reads

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)
```

I get an error of

> Object Variable or with block variable not set

**Full New Code**

```
Option Compare Database
Sub RefreshLinkedTables()
Dim searchdirs() As Variant
Dim sdir As Variant
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim colFiles As Collection

Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = ".mdb$|.accdb$"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

Set colFiles = New Collection

searchdirs = Array("C:\Test\", "R:\", "T:\")

For Each sdir In searchdirs
    RecursiveFileSearch sdir, objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO

    For Each f In colFiles
        Debug.Print f
    Next

Next

End Sub
Sub RecursiveFileSearch(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByRef objRegExp As Object, _
                ByRef matchedFiles As Collection, ByRef objFSO As Object)

Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objSubFolders As Object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)
For Each objFile In objFolder.files
    If objRegExp.test(objFile) Then
        matchedFiles.Add (objFile)
    End If
Next
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the targetFolder parameter to an array of strings then loop over that to search each location

Comment: @TimWilliams - will you add an example?  I am lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over an array of folder paths

```
Dim v As Variant
For Each v In Array("C:\Test\", "R:\", "T:\")
    RecursiveFileSearch Cstr(v), objRegExp, colFiles, objFSO
Next
```

Comment: I get an error of 'object variable or with block variable not set' see my edited code.

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights need to declare objFSO in RefreshLinkedTables `Dim objFSO  as Object:Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the assistance!  I mistakenly had commented that out in my initial post and removed for te updated.

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights thanks for accepting my answer.. Cheers!